# Match the next word after a regex expression

Tags: regex, expression, lookbehind

I want to match a word after a regex expression.

For e.g I came up with a regex expression to match date and time - `<Apr 11, 2017 2:35:53 AM SGT>`

```
<(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June|July|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s(\d\d?).+?(\d\d\d\d)\s\b((1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([AaPp][Mm])\sSGT)>
```

[Can see that it works here](http://rubular.com/r/0NeK0TT6Ye)

I want to take it further to match the word after this regex.

```
Apr 12, 2017, 10:56:22 AM   Hello   #### <Apr 12, 2017 2:27:08 AM SGT> <Info>
```

So it should only match the word `<Info>` but it highlighted

```
 12, 2017, 10:56:22 AM Hello #### <Apr 12, 2017 2:27:08 AM SGT> <Info>
```

[My regex expression](http://rubular.com/r/0NeK0TT6Ye)

Appreciate every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to grab `<info>`, just extand your regex to match the next word:

```
<(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|June|July|Aug|Sept|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d\d?.+?\d\d\d\d\s\b(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\s[AaPp][Mm]\sSGT>\s(<\w+>)
```

[Example](http://rubular.com/r/GjSouNhSbU).